# LOLIPOP!マネージドクラウド環境でのOracleInstant導入

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, oracle

LOLIPOP!マネージドクラウドのNode.js用コンテナにデプロイしたアプリからnode-oracledbでリモートのOracleDBに接続しようとしているのですが下記エラーが発生してしまい接続できません。

```
Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library:
"libnnz21.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
directory". See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
for help   Node-oracledb installation instructions:
https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html   You must have
64-bit Oracle Client libraries configured with ldconfig, or in
LD_LIBRARY_PATH.   If you do not have Oracle Database on this
computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package
from   
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html
```

root権限が与えられていないため、OracleInstantをホームディレクトリ配下にwgetコマンドで上記にも記載されているページからZIP版をダウンロード・解凍してインストールしました。(Basic・Lightどちらも試しています)

環境変数 `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` には上記のパスである `/var/app/shared/oracle/instantclient_21_6` をLOLIPOPの管理画面から登録済みで `PATH` にも同パスを追記しています。
なお、`ORACLE_HOME` は設定していません。

実際のDB接続処理は下記の通りです(initOracleClient()でエラー)

```
Logger.info(`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${process.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`);
Logger.info(`PATH=${process.env.PATH}`);
Logger.info(`ORACLE_LIB_DIR=${config.oracleLibDir}`);
oracledb.initOracleClient({ libDir: config.oracleLibDir });

[2022-07-10T14:54:16.739] [INFO] system - LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/app/shared/oracle/instantclient_21_6
[2022-07-10T14:54:16.739] [INFO] system - PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/app/1657432410488792/node_modules/.bin:/var/app/1657432410488792/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/app/1657432410488792/node_modules/.bin:/var/app/shared/oracle/instantclient_21_6:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/app/1657213958461238/node_modules/.bin:/var/app/.npm/_npx/14/bin:/var/app/1657213958461238/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/app/1657213958461238/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[2022-07-10T14:54:16.739] [INFO] system - ORACLE_LIB_DIR=/var/app/shared/oracle/instantclient_21_6
```

エラーメッセージ的にはパスが通っていないような気もするのですが、そもそも非rootでは動作しないものなのでしょうか？
ちなみに手元にあるWindows環境では同様のアプリとWindows版OracleInstantでDBに接続できることを確認しています。
Linux系はほとんど知識がないため困っています。何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
node-oracledb ver.5.3.0
OracleInstant(instantclient_21_6)

---追記---
https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#instzipより、

> You will need the operating system libaio package installed. On some
> platforms the package is called libaio1.

とのことなので当該パッケージを手動でダウンロードして下記コマンドでインストールしてみましたがエラー内容含めて変わらずでした。
`dpkg -x libaio1_0.3.112-13build1_amd64.deb /var/app/shared/oracle/instantclient_21_6/libaio`

Comment: 「LD_LIBRARY_PATH は管理画面から設定済み」との事ですが、実際にコマンドを実行する段階で LD_LIBRARY_PATH に反映されているかは確認できますか？

Comment: エラーと直接の関係は無いかもしれませんが、Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS は延長サポートを購入していない限り既に EOL な点は注意した方が良いかと。

Comment: @cubick OSについてのご指摘、ありがとうございました。環境変数については接続直前にログ出力した結果を記載しました。環境変数には問題ないように思うのですが、やはりエラーが出ています・・・

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATHについて、管理画面から設定したと思っていたのですが、エラーが発生しており登録できておらず、実際にはenvファイルに書いていた内容が有効になっていたようです。node-oracledbの要件としてNode.js起動前に環境変数を設定する必要があるとのことなのでこれが原因かもしれません。現在LOLIPOPの方に管理画面からLD_LIBRARY_PATHを登録できない原因と対処法を問い合わせ中です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
結論から言うとLOLIPOP!マネージドクラウド環境でのnode-oracledbによるDB接続は難しそうです。

まずはじめに、node-oracledbはアプリ側で環境変数を設定することもできるとしながらも、`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`は例外的にNode.js起動前に設定されている必要がある?ようです
https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-154-oracle-environment-variables

> It is recommended to set Oracle variables in the environment before
> invoking Node.js, however they may also be set in application code as
> long as they are set before node-oracledb is first used. System
> environment variables like LD_LIBRARY_PATH must be set before Node.js
> starts.

件の環境ではアプリ側envファイルで`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`を設定してしまっていたため、DB接続処理時にエラーとなっているようです。
そのため、LOLIPOP管理画面より環境変数`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`を設定しようとしましたが登録時にエラーとなりました。
これをLOLIPOPに問い合わせた結果、`LD_XXXXX`という変数名の一部はセキュリティの都合で設定できない仕様であるとのことでした。

node-oracledbによるDB接続は諦めてOracleCloudのRESTfulServiceでHTTPリクエストによるDBアクセスを検討してみようと思います・・・